# XAML Listbox Style Override Control Template for Order Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Most of the tutorials and questions I see are about restyling the listbox to look different, but I'm interested in adding additional controls to make it behave differently. I initially started out trying to make the list builder control out of a checkbox list, but found myself too deep. I decided to abstract and start with a smaller problem.

What I am looking to do first, to get a better understanding of how this works is add "up" and "down" buttons next to the control. I think this can all be done in xaml, so to try and pressure myself to stick to that I'm working in Kaxaml.

[image: Items from the list can be reordered using the buttons up and down.]

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
  <!-- ListBox Order Button Style 
          Col 1
            Listbox
          Col 2
            Buttons Up and Down
  -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBox}" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                <Rectangle Fill="Yellow"/>
                <!--<ListBox></ListBox>-->
              </Grid>
              <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <Button>Up</Button>
                <Button>Down</Button>
              </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>

  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>  
  <ListBox>
    <TextBlock>Value 1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Value 2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Value 3</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>Value 4</TextBlock>
  </ListBox>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

I am currently hung up on a few things.

1) When I try to use a ListBox where the Yellow Rectangle is I start getting infinite loop problems.

2) I'm not sure how to connect the buttons to the listbox once it is there. I think Triggers is the answer, but I don't have much experience with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your infinite loop can be addressed by not relying on the `TargetType` to apply the style. Instead, apply the style explicitly via a named key (i.e. something other than `{x:Type Listbox}`). That way the style is applied only when you specifically want it to be applied.

"Connecting" the buttons can be done a variety of ways. The simplest would be to handle the `Button.Click` event and perform whatever action you want there.

All that said, I think you're going about this the wrong way. Let a `ListBox` be a `ListBox`; don't try to make it into something it's not. If you want a reusable control that adds functionality around a `ListBox`, like buttons to control the contents of the `ListBox`, you should probably be authoring a `UserControl`, which is essentially a composite control made up of whatever you want.

Doing so will give you a lot more control over the appearance of the control. You'll also have the opportunity to declare dependency properties on your control that are specific to exactly what that control needs to support (something you can't do just with a `Style`). Yes, it also means you'll have to expose properties of contained elements via new properties in your `UserControl` that effectively delegate to the contained elements, but that's a small price to pay for the flexibility and relative simplicity of creating the `UserControl` in the first place.

Comment: How would you accomplish this in XAML as an implicit style? ie. this style would apply to all controls of type listbox.

Comment: You don't. Your question is specifically asking how _not_ to do that. If you apply the style to _all_ `ListBox` elements, that will include the one in the yellow box, which you don't want.

Comment: But, that would imply that you can't make an implicit style that overrides the control template and includes the control you are using.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As I said, "implicit style" and "include in the template the control type the implicit style applies to" are mutually exclusive. At least one of the outer control and inner control (e.g. your `ListBox` in this case) will need an _explicitly_ assigned style, to avoid the infinite recursion. That said, I reiterate: I don't think `ControlTemplate` is really the right way to go here anyway. If you have something that's a "`ListBox`-plus", make a `UserControl` that encapsulates what you want, so you can still use plain `ListBox` controls elsewhere.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So, the listbox in the overridden control template must be explicitly provided a style itself.

Comment: One or the other does. As I wrote above, I wouldn't use the control template at all for this purpose. If I _were_ to use it for this purpose, I would not make the style that sets the control template to be the implicit style; it is _that_ one I would set explicitly. But yes, you can also choose to set the inner `ListBox` element's style explicitly instead if you prefer.